Issue when loading data from database to json file
I am using a SSIS package to load data from database to a JSON file.When the name is like 'OĞUA HILL' then the data is stored in the json file as '0\u011eUA HILL'.Similarly when there are names like Ğ or Ángel then it is stored in file in the decoded format.
Can you please guide on how can I handle this.
Thanks in advance.

What exactly is the problem with that? Both should be legal, but many JSON serializers escape out non-ASCII unicode characters to ensure the characters are serialized exactly as written in the text. In other words, do you need to handle this?

To be more specific, the json expression "O\u011eUA HILL" should deserialize to the string value OĞUA HILL. If it doesn't do that, you have a broken JSON deserializer.

Yes,I need to handle this.The users don't want the decoded text

Your users want O\u011eUA HILL? Then you can't deserialize the JSON. Or are you saying that you want to serialize to JSON and have it serialized as "OĞUA HILL"? Then your users are not JSON compliant because this is legal JSON and JSON serializers are allowed to do this in accordance with the specification. If your users have a broken JSON deserializer, then either you hack it together, or your users fix or replace their JSON serializer.

Some serializers can be configured to allow or disallow such escape sequences unless absolutely necessary, but deserialization will absolutely return "OĞUA HILL", because that's what they're supposed to do.

However, it's not altogether clear what your users want here, are they consuming the deserialized string or the JSON? Please specify more details about the process here and what the actual problem is.

@LasseV.Karlsen i guess his deserializers are users sitting with notepad and staring at json all day

The users dont want the decoded data they just want the name 'OĞUA HILL'.How can I show only this name in the json file.
